# unable to get the data from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php, json

I was doing some table work on client side after that i need to send all the selected rows of the table to a php file for further processing. For that i have used JSON ....the data which I am sending is as ....

```
[Object { 6=true, product_Id="10", product_name="pn5", more...}, 
Object { 6=true, product_Id="12", product_name="pn7", more...}, 
Object { row_count=2}]
```

Now i am sending this `via $.post('abc.php',data);`.But now the problem starts that how parse this data in my php file as if i do `$ret=$_REQUEST['data'];` than ***I get error***...so please let me know the correct way......

My javascript code is...

```
var data1=obj.dataModel.data;
var json_object;
var exportExcel=new Array();
var exportExcel1=new Array();

console.log(data1);
//console.log()

for(var i = 0; i < selected_index.length; i++)
{
     var rowIndex = selected_index[i].rowIndx;
     json_object = data1[rowIndex];

     //push the data in the array
     exportExcel.push(json_object);
     //console.log(json_object);
}

exportExcel.push({row_count:selected_index.length});   //APPENDING DATA!!

var myExcel = JSON.stringify(exportExcel);
console.log(exportExcel);
//console.log(JSON.parse(myExcel));
$.post('stock_low_Excel.php', function(msg){
    if(msg == 1)
    {
        alert("send");
    }
});
```

and my php file code is....

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 */
//getting the data.....
$data = $_REQUEST['object'];
//echo($data);
echo(1);
?>
```

now I want to know that how can I get the data sent by my JavaScript file in my php file....and how to parse the data which I am getting

Comment: what error are you getting? can we see some more code? you're gonna need to give us more information if you're looking for help

Comment: the javascript code is

Comment: add it to the question please and format your question properly

Comment: you are missing a single quote in `$ret=$_REQUEST['data];`...

Comment: sorry this was an error in typing on stack over flow...but in my original file its correct...

Comment: Can you send the data as a JSON representable string which can be captured in `$_POST/$_GET/$_REQUEST` var of PHP and on PHP side you make use of `json_decode()` in-order to convert the string into PHP object

Comment: how to send data as JSON representable string...as i am sending a JSON data only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely want to wrap the json-objects(/collection) as they are send as 0={...};1={...}

```
$.post("my_php_file.php", {"stock_data":data}, function(data) {
     console.log(data); 
     alert(data.message);
});
```

and then from php:

```
<?php
$in = isset($_POST['stock_data']) ? $_POST['stock_data'] : false;
if($in !== false) {
    $data = json_decode($in, true);
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'success', 'data' => $data));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'no data received'));
}
```

Comment: thanks ...for it...bit now i am getting a Error as   Warning</b>:  json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\work1\aid\stock_low_Excel.php

Comment: but in the POST pannel of my php file i can see the data as data[0][6] true
data[0][company] pm10
data[0][min_stock] 25
data[0][product_Id] 15
data[0][product_name] pn10
data[0][quantity] 20
data[0][selectedRow] true
data[1][6] true
data[1][company] pm2
data[1][min_stock] 25
data[1][product_Id] 7
data[1][product_name] pn2
data[1][quantity] 20
data[1][selectedRow] true
data[2][row_count] 2